# Mongoengine + Python Class __init__

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm new to MongoEngine , and trying to integrate it within a larger python application.

1. Can you initialize MongoEngine inheriting-document-classes with a super().**init**?
2. And does every class attribute need to be a mongoengine field?

For example:

```
import mongoengine as me
class GenericItem(me.Document):
    
    # MongoEngine Fields    
    amount = me.IntField(min_value=1,required=True)
    price = me.EmbeddedDocumentField(PriceClass, required = True)
    trade_date = me.DateTimeField(required = True)

    # Document-Admin Fields
    last_update_date = me.DateField()
    document_version = me.IntField(default=1)

    # mongoengine stuff:    
    meta = {'collection' : 'BlotterCollection',
            'allow_inheritance': True}    
    
    def __init__(self, trade : CustomTradeClass, *args, **kwargs):
        super(me.Document, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
              
        self.trade = trade 
        self.amount = self.trade.amount
        self.price = self.trade.price
        self.trade_date = self.trade.trade_date
```

In this case, self.trade isn't a mongoengine field.  However its attributes etc populate many of the other fields.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to fill in the other fields when saving the model?

Comment: Yeah, I want to pass complex objects into the ModelObject(Document) __init__, so that I can then extract stuff out of it.